# Slick (Scalaquery) - insert gives type error

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scalaquery

I am using Slick (Scalaquery) in my play framework application. According to [slick tutorial](https://github.com/slick/slick/wiki/Inserting-and-Updating) - I can define a projection for columns I want to insert into. (I am defining this projection because my index is an auto-incrementing column.) But, when I use this projection in an insert, I get a type-error saying:

```
[NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;].
```

My model is defined like this:

```
package models

import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current

import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.ql.{MappedTypeMapper}
import scala.slick.session.{Session, Database}

case class Book(name: String, filename: String)

object Book extends Table[(Long, String, String)]("book") {

  lazy val database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())
  def id = column[Long]("id", O PrimaryKey, O AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name", O NotNull)
  def filename = column[String]("filename", O NotNull)
  def * = id ~ name ~ filename
  def withoutId = name ~ filename

  def findAll() : Seq[Book] = database.withSession { implicit db:Session =>
    (for(t <- this) yield t.name ~ t.filename).list.map(attrs => Book(attrs._1, attrs._2))
  }

  def create(book: Book): Unit = database.withSession { implicit db:Session =>
    this.withoutId insert(book.name, book.filename)
  }

}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
! @6b1eg7f2d - Internal server error, for request [POST /addBook] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.augmentString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at scala.slick.driver.BasicSQLUtilsComponent$class.quoteIdentifier(BasicSQLUtilsComponent.scala:12) ~[slick_2.10.0-M4-0.10.0-M2.jar:0.10.0-M2]
    at scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver$.quoteIdentifier(PostgresDriver.scala:69) ~[slick_2.10.0-M4-0.10.0-M2.jar:0.10.0-M2]
    at scala.slick.driver.BasicStatementBuilderComponent$InsertBuilder.appendNamedColumn(BasicStatementBuilderComponent.scala:400) ~[slick_2.10.0-M4-0.10.0-M2.jar:0.10.0-M2]
    at scala.slick.driver.BasicStatementBuilderComponent$InsertBuilder.scala$slick$driver$BasicStatementBuilderComponent$InsertBuilder$$f$1(BasicStatementBuilderComponent.scala:387) ~[slick_2.10.0-M4-0.10.0-M2.jar:0.10.0-M2]
    at scala.slick.driver.BasicStatementBuilderComponent$InsertBuilder$$anonfun$scala$slick$driver$BasicStatementBuilderComponent$InsertBuilder$$f$1$1.apply$mcVI$sp(BasicStatementBuilderComponent.scala:377) ~[slick_2.10.0-M4-0.10.0-M2.jar:0.10.0-M2]
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:75) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
```

Can someone help me by pointing out what's wrong with my insert?

Comment: The versions in the jars strongly suggests that you facing binary incompatibility: Slick (slick_2.10.0-M4-0.10.0-M2.jar) is compiled for Scala 2.10.0-M4, while play (play_2.9.1-2.0.2.jar) and others are compiled for 2.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLICK is not supported on Scala 2.9 (as used by Play). All "proper" SLICK builds (in the scala.slick namepace and with the new frontend) require Scala 2.10.0-M4 or -M5. The latest supported version on Scala 2.9 is ScalaQuery 0.10.0-M1.

Judging by the feature you're using in the snippet, everything should work the same way with ScalaQuery 0.10.0-M1 or even 0.9 (except for the different imports).